# Selection Symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, select

In ArcMap, I can change the selection outline from the default RGB (0, 255, 255) to whatever color I want by going to Selection > Selection Options > Selection Tools Settings.  In the example below, I have set my selection color to a red outline.
[image: ArcMap Selection Color Example]

I'm trying to do the same in QGIS, but the entire polygon is shaded red, instead of with just a red outline like I can do in ArcMap.  [image: QGIS Selection Symbology Example]

Is it possible to achieve similar selection display in QGIS as I can in ArcMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far it is not possible. ArcMap selection method is based on selecting the outline of the polygon, which means when you do selection in ArcMap, it will highlight the outline. whereas in QGIS it is the contrary. The QGIS selection method is based on the fill of the polygon. When you do selection in QGIS the polygon fill will be highlighted and there no option to highlight just the outline.

ArcMAp Selection:

[image]

QGIS Selection:

[image]

You can apply for feature request to the QGIS team developer if you are interested in this feature in QGIS [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html).

Comment: You can change the color of the selection in the project->properties menu

Comment: @IanTurton That is correct, and the OP can do the same thing from `Settings -> Options -> Canvas & Legend` but only the fill color not the outline.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was needing to know.

Comment: The one exception is when you have the layer style set to `Outline: Simple Line`. When you select a feature with this style setting, the outline of the feature is highlighted in yellow (or whatever color you chose in project properties).